# OrientDB messages unread count

Tags: sql, graph, orientdb

I currently have the following graph in my OrientDB database:

[image: Database Graph]

Which contains of the following properties:

[image: Database Schema]'

Basically a `User` can be part of a so called `Thread`, this is set by the `IsMember` edge. If they are a member they are able to send a `Message` to a Thread.

Inside the IsMember edge there is also a `last_read` property which is of the type DateTime, this is a date of when they last opened the Thread. So if we try and get all the Messages with a newer `created_at` we get all the unread Message's. A query to accomplish this could look like this **(cluster 12=users 14=thread)**:

```
SELECT * FROM Message 
    let $LR = (select lastRead.asLong() from IsMember where in = #12:1320782 AND out = #14:705856)
WHERE in = #14:705856 AND out = #12:1320782 AND created_at.asLong() > $LR[0].lastRead
```

This is great and all but I would like to show a unread counter for all the Threads. Using this query for all the Threads a User is a Member of would in some cases use up to 200-300 queries.

So basically I am looking for a query that is able to get all the unread Messages of all the threads a User is a member of.

**Extra usefull queries**:
A query to get all the subscribed Threads of a User would look something like this:

```
select expand(out) from (
  select * from IsMember where in = 12:1320782
)
```

Query to get the lastRead property from a given User and Thread

```
select lastRead.asLong() from IsMember where in = #12:1320782 AND out = #14:705856
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select in.nick as user ,out.title as thread ,$a.size() as count from IsMember
let $a=(select created_at from Message where out.nick=$parent.current.in.nick and in.title=$parent.current.out.title and created_at > $parent.current.last_read)
```

Comment: I changed it a bit and came up with the following:

select 
  out as thread,
  $a.size() as count
from IsMember
let 
  $a=(select created_at from Message where in = $parent.current.out.@rid AND created_at > $parent.current.last_read)
where in = #12:1320782

...However the inner query ($a) takes too long since it fetches more than 5000 records, seems like the $parent.current is the culprit? If I replace that with a static RID it is fast.

Comment: How many are the edges isMember and Message ?
How many are the vertexes User and Thread ?

Comment: Try this query: select nick,title,count(*) as _count from (select from (select mex.created_at,mex.in.title as title2,* from (select rid.outE("Message") as mex,* from 
(select rid, nick,isMem.last_read as last_read,isMem.out.title as title from (select @rid,nick, inE("isMember") as isMem from user unwind isMem)) unwind mex)) where title=title2 and mex>last_read) group by nick,title

Comment: Thanks a ton, had to tweak the query a bit but the end result is perfect! Once again thanks for you help your a hero ;)